# SQL Server Agent Job doesn't execute SSIS package on schedule

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Server Agent Job that has a single step to run an SSIS package at 7:00 am in the morning. On an average day it completes within 1.5 hours. Sometimes it will delay up to 3 hours. When I check the log in agent job I can see that it started on time and it took over 3 hours to complete. When I check the SSIS package history log I can see that the package was executed at 9:25 and completed at 10:45. It seems that something is holding up the package from executing.

The SSIS package runs several sql tasks to rebuild tables and import data. It is set to run using Sql Server Integration Services Package type and a SQL_AGENT_PROXY account with the required credentials. The package is run from SSIS Catalog.

How can I troubleshoot to see what's holding up the package from starting or what other issues may cause this to happen?

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to really begin to do anything but guess. There's no code, no detail of what the package does, not details of the way your executing said package in agent, how the package is deployed, etc,etc.

Comment: I added some details that I thought were applicable. Anything else I should still add?

Comment: Check to see if there is any locking/blocking.

Comment: It could be taking a long time to validate the package or the external metadata. If you don't need them, I would try setting them to false to see if that helps your package gets started quicker. If possible, log into your SQL Server at 7am and watch the processes. I'd start with `sp_who2` and go from there.